# In C++, how do I use symbol «×» instead of «*» for multiplication? Preprocessor and operator overloading are of no help for this

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, preprocessor

I hate when asterisk symbol is used for multiplication. It is ugly, and looks like pointer dereference operator.

I tried to use preprocessor:

```
#define × *
```

But the compiler says that «Macro name must be an identifier». What do I do?

Comment: Just don't.  As much as you may not like it, `*` is the multiplication operator is most/all languages.  Changing that violates the principal of least surprise

Comment: Please never use non-ASCII identifiers, especially not those which look like ASCII. If you do this I assure you, any users/readers of the code will hate you more than you hate `*`.

Comment: @Quimby you are probably right that `×` looks a bit like `x`. In this case, I would agree to use `⋅` for multiplication: `x⋅y`. Meantime, my Swift colleagues define custom operators such as `⊕`. I feel deprived!

Comment: You kinda accept that most languages aren't designed for math and you live with writing ugly stuff. That said, there's Julia which specifically wants to address this.

Answer (score 3):

Let me preface this answer with a recommendation to never do this.

---

Given your title, yes this is somewhat possible:

```
template <typename T>
struct Y {
    T const& i;
    friend auto operator>>(Y y, T const& j) {
        return y.i * j;
    }
};
struct X {
    template <typename T>
    friend auto operator<<(T const& i, X) {
        return Y<T>{i};
    }
};
inline X x;
```

This will allow multiplications of the form `operandA <<x>> operandB`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << (6 <<x>> 7) << "\n"; // prints 42
}
```

The operator overloads are [optimised out by the compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf9j97Mqv), but it will most decidedly *not* be optimised out by any human brain reading your code. Don't do this.

Comment: Pretty sure the `<< >>` part is just how the OP quotes things, not the actual operator they want.  In the Question body they want to replace `*` with `×`

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand that this is a joke by literally interpreting my question. Very cool!

I will upvote but will not mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: Not so much a joke. It's just that `6 x 7` cannot work (except if you use a `#define`). So the only way is to take OP literally. However, note that you can extend this to basically define any infix operator you like: `opA <<fancyOp>> opB`.

Comment: Useless, but upvoted for such a great abuse of operator overload.